# Why don't stepper motors ring indefinitely?

Tags: electromagnetism

This is a copy of the question on the electronics stack exchange site:

I don't have much of a EM background but I have used stepper motors for things. What's not clear to me is why don't stepper motors ring indefinitely?

Excluding physical friction, what actually causes a stepper motor to stop at a given location? It's clear how the acceleration takes place to the next position - there is an induced magnetic field which forces the motor turn. But once that acceleration has taken place and the shaft reaches the next step location, significant momentum has been built up and the shaft is traveling at a certain rotational velocity. This will result in the motor over shooting the step location - while it's clear the magnetic field will attempt to accelerate the shaft in the other direction once over-shoot occurs, it seems energy is simply being added to the system producing a harmonic oscillator.

Could someone explain what mechanism is causing energy to leave the system?

If it was frictionless, would oscillation be indefinite?

Answer (score 3):

To stop the stepper motor, it is common to disconnect the electric power and then either short-circuit together the last set of windings which were energized or connect them through a low-resistance resistor. This is called *dynamic braking* and it dissipates the rotational energy of the stepper rotor by turning the motor into a generator and then wasting the current generated in that load resistor or in the resistance of the windings themselves.